# extracting html content from gitlab url

Tags: github, gitlab

I'm trying to get the html content from gitlab url.
But I was struck at Gitlab sign-in page and I am getting html content of sign-in page even after providing username and password.

Code:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
    import requests
    username = "username"
    password = "password"
    url = "HTTP://gitlab.com/saikumar/webhooktslint"
    result=requests.get(url, auth=("username", "password")).content  /* 
    gets 
    content from the site */
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result,'lxml')
    for link in soup:
       print link
```

Output:

```
   Getting HTML content of sign_in page.
```

Expected output:

```
   Need to get the HTML content of the URL specified.
```

Comment: code:-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
username = "username"
password = "password"
url = "https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in"

result=requests.get("https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in", auth=("username", "password")).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(result,'lxml')
for link in soup:
   print link

Comment: Any kind of answer is much appreciated in python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a repo `webhooktslint` in your [`gitlab.com/saikumar`](https://gitlab.com/saikumar) page, so it is likely to be a private repository.

Looking at [python GitLab CLI usage](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html), make sure to properly set your `~/.python-gitlab.cfg` user configuration file, with a [GitLab private token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) in it: you won't have to deal with credentials then.

The gitlab python command will do the curl for you, including to [get the raw data of a file](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/gitlab.v4.html?highlight=raw#gitlab.v4.objects.Project.repository_raw_blob).

But that same private token can help authenticate you when trying to do a GET of a private repo as you do in your code (if you are after the actual HTML page content).

Main point, to access a private repo, use a PAT (Personal Access Token) rather than your actual account password.