# Get Gitlab link page content in html

Tags: python, html, gitlab

I am having the same use case as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673936/extracting-html-content-from-gitlab-url/61075448#61075448). I would like to access to the gitlab page to get html page content (private repo) but it always direct me to sign in page even I already pass the authentication which I refer to [here](https://gist.github.com/gpocentek/bd4c3fbf8a6ce226ebddc4aad6b46c0a)

Below is my code:

```
import urllib, re, sys, requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

LOGIN_URL = 'https://gitlab.devtools.com//users/auth/ldapmain/callback'

session = requests.Session()

data = {'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'authenticity_token': token}
r = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=data)

print r.status_code
url = "https://gitlab.devtools.com/Sandbox/testing/merge_requests/2" 
html = session.get(url)
print html.url
```

Any idea on this? Am I missing anything?

Comment: what don't you use the API to get this kind of information ?

Comment: hi, i do not use Gitlab API because the information (merge request dependencies) that i want to get is not supported by API. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_dependencies.html. So, I am thinking to access to the Gitlab merge request page and get the information that i want through html content. Is that possible?